# Panda resampling function does not work with 'MS' frequency

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to use the resample function with a monthly frequency that starts every month on the same day ('MS') but I can not make it work.

I have a dataframe:

```
aux.head()
Out[27]: 
           IDENTIFICADOR      FECHA  Inyectividad  Arena
FECHA                                                   
2011-07-29     CoHS-1022 2011-07-29           0.0   0.01
2011-07-30     CoHS-1022 2011-07-30           0.0   0.02
2011-07-31     CoHS-1022 2011-07-31           0.0   0.05
2011-01-08     CoHS-1022 2011-01-08           0.0   0.02
2011-02-08     CoHS-1022 2011-02-08           0.0   0.01
```

if I use the monthly frequency 'M':

```
mensual['Arena'] = aux['Arena'].resample('M').mean()
```

I get:

```
mensual.head()
Out[29]: 
            Arena
FECHA            
2011-01-31  0.112
2011-02-28  0.108
2011-03-31  0.122
2011-04-30  0.110
2011-05-31  0.100
```

but I want all the months to start all with the same day, 
like:

```
            Arena
FECHA            
2011-01-1  some mean value
2011-02-1  some mean value
2011-03-1  some mean value
2011-04-1  some mean value
2011-05-1  some mean value
```

so i tried:

```
mensual['Arena'] = aux['Arena'].resample('MS').mean()
```

But i get:

```
mensual.head()
Out[32]: 
            Arena
FECHA            
2011-01-31    NaN
2011-02-28    NaN
2011-03-31    NaN
2011-04-30    NaN
2011-05-31    NaN
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you change all columns `FECHA` iterating through the column and later `resample` with `MS`? It seems that `NaN` is derivative of the fact that you don't have any `Arena` data in the begging of the month.

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi iterating is usually not a good idea in pandas

Comment: Version '0.23.4' of pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pd.offsets.MonthBegin`

```
s = df['Arena'].resample('M').mean()
s.index = s.index - pd.offsets.MonthBegin(1)
```